# Do I need to scale before performing Wilcoxon test?

Tags: r

I'm running Wilcoxon rank sum test on my data. The data is of different units and largely different scales.
Do I need to type in this command before running the test?

```
## where x is my data frame
scale(x, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)
```

or does the Wilcoxon rank sum test inherently do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't scale because Wilcoxon is a location test (default in R is mu=0) and, if you scale your data, you will lose the true location information.

```
> x <- rnorm(100,700,20)
> 
> wilcox.test(x) # Mu = 0

        Wilcoxon signed rank test with continuity correction

data:  x 
V = 5050, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true location is not equal to 0 

> wilcox.test(x,mu=mean(x))

        Wilcoxon signed rank test with continuity correction

data:  x 
V = 2650, p-value = 0.6686
alternative hypothesis: true location is not equal to 697.4377 

> wilcox.test(scale(x))  # Mu = 0

        Wilcoxon signed rank test with continuity correction

data:  scale(x) 
V = 2650, p-value = 0.6686
alternative hypothesis: true location is not equal to 0
```

Comment: Cool I understand what you did here, although there is a question on my mind, comparing the V value between the 1st and the 3rd test you performed. Did the V value went down because the values in the x matrix were closer to each other after scaling?

Comment: The V value went down because the  'real' ('real' because it's after scaling) location went closer to mu value. In the first case, we have location equal to 697.43 and mu equal to 0, and the 3rd location AND mu equal to 0. The 2nd we have location and mu equal to 697.43, that's why it gave the same V value of the 3rd test (in both tests, mu and location have the same distance, 0).